# Main function not executing in Pydev Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, function, program-entry-point, pydev

When I run the code in Pydev, main function is not executing. I dont see any errors though. I am using Pyton-3.9, Eclipse 4.2 and PyDev 8.3

When i have written the code outside of main, it got executed. But whatever the code inside the main() is not executing and i dont see any errors.

Ex:
Case 1:

```
print ("Hello, world!") # Executed and printed "Hello World"
```

Case 2:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

        print ("Hello, world!") # In this case i dont see "Hello World" printed.
```

I also tried calling main() like below but didnt work.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    print ("Hello, world!")
```

I am not sure what i am missing. Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried `print(__name__)`? What does it print?

Comment: Are you sure that the edit made is correct? The pre-edit version didn't include `__main__` @Paul M.....

Comment: @BTables Thanks for double-checking, but yes I'm sure. The double underscores were actually already there, it just didn't look like it because Stack Overflow's formatter will turn text within `__` bold. If you view the edit history, and click on the side-by-side markdown tab, you'll see they were already there.

Comment: @Paul M. Ah interesting. That’s a fun new factoid for me!

Answer (score 0):

Some questions to help diagnose the issue:

1. Are you doing a regular run (i.e.:just `F9` with that editor in focus) on the editor or are you debugging?
2. Are you sure you're not running a different file/module and that one is just being imported?
3. To help diagnose that, can you post the output of running the code below in that module?

```
print('name:')
print(__name__)

print('sys.argv:')
import sys
print(sys.argv)

print('stack:')
import traceback
traceback.print_stack()
```